# passing filepath from vba to python on mac

Tags: python-3.x, vba

I am trying to pass a file path from a vba script to a python3 script using the following code:

```
Sub py_from_vba()
    Dim scriptPath As String
    Dim gpxFilePath As String
    Dim command As String

    ' Specify the path to your Python script
    scriptPath = "/Volumes/256SSD/Fitness_and_health/Walking_records/new_data/python_progs/read_gpx.py"

    ' Specify the GPX file path you want to pass
    gpxFilePath = "/Volumes/256SSD/Fitness_and_health/Walking_records/new_data/route_2024-01-10_10.39am.gpx"

    ' Build the shell command to run the Python script with the GPX file path as an argument
    command = "python3 " & scriptPath & " """ & gpxFilePath & """"
MsgBox command
    ' Execute the shell command
    Call Shell(command, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

at the MsgBox the correct value for command is given but the Call Shell statement fails with an error Run time error 76 Path not found.

If I copy the command from MsgBox and run that in a Terminal window, the python script works correctly.
So the paths in the command are not be correctly passed to the script.

Command actually contains

python3 /Volumes/256SSD/Fitness_and_health/Walking_records/new_data/python_progs/read_gpx.py "/Volumes/256SSD/Fitness_and_health/Walking_records/new_data/route_2024-01-10_10.39am.gpx"

Can someone help please?

Comment: The thing with running scripts is that the execution environment might be a bit different. Have you tried running ```Call Shell("python3 -V", vbNormalFocus)```? (Note, I don't know VBA... just copying your shell command)  Why does your second path need ```"```?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried running with the call shell as you suggested  - no luck, still get the same error. I dont know why the second path needs". I was following an example from elsewhere. I tried running the command in the terminal window without the "" and that ran OK.

Comment: If you're getting the same error as the first,  it's most likely complaining that it can't find the python binary.  Perhaps actually using the full path for the python3 binary?